# Список стандартных сообщений об ошибках на английском языке

Tags: node.js

Где можно найти список стандартных сообщений об ошибках на английском языке?
Например: пользователь не найден или введен не корретный пароль и т.д.

Comment: Как метка относится к вопросу?

Answer (score 2):

Вот лист всех List of HTTP status codes :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

пример из ссилки:

```
400 Bad Request

401 Unauthorized (RFC 7235)

402 Payment Required

403 Forbidden

404 Not Found

405 Method Not Allowed
```

Comment: Это не то. Мне не нужны список стандартных http кодов ошибок. Нужны именно тексты сообщений. Не хочу их придумывать, а хочу использовать стандартные сообщения.

Comment: Никаких стандартных сообщений не существует.